# SQL Hierarchy and Joined Table Counts

Tags: sql, recursion

I have a  Employee Table and a Projects table. An employee can only be in 1 proj and have the employee table as a hierarchy with ID and ReportsTO ID . I need to get the counts of the projects where the managers count will be the aggregate of the employees under him and so on...

```
    DECLARE @Employees TABLE (EmpID INT, EmpName VARCHAR(20), ReportsTo INT)
INSERT INTO @Employees(EmpID, EmpName, ReportsTo)
  SELECT 1, 'Jacob', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 'Rui', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 'Jacobson', NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'Jess', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, 'Steve', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, 'Bob', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, 'Smith', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, 'Bobbey', 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 9, 'Steffi', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 10, 'Bracha', 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 11, 'John', 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT 12, 'Michael', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 13, 'Paul', 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 14, 'Lana', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 15, 'Johnson', 7 UNION ALL
  SELECT 16, 'Mic', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 17, 'Stev', 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 18, 'Paulson', 9 UNION ALL
  SELECT 19, 'Jessica', 10

DECLARE @Projects Table (ID INT,EMPID INT, PROJNAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @PROJECTS(ID,EMPID,PROJNAME)  
    SELECT 1,19,'ABCD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,5,'EFGH'   UNION ALL

    SELECT 3,16,'ADAD'  UNION ALL

    SELECT 4,6,'FSDFSD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,8,'DSDSDSD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,8,'DSDSADDSD'



--Solution starts here
DECLARE @manager VARCHAR(20)
SELECT @manager ='JACOB'

--CTE
;With Hierarchy(EmpName, EmpID, Level, FullyQualifiedName)
As
(
  Select E.EmpName, E.EmpID, 0, Cast('.'+E.EmpName+'.' as Varchar(MAX))
    From @Employees E
    Where E.ReportsTo is null
  Union all
  Select E.EmpName, E.EmpID, H.Level+1, H.FullyQualifiedName+'.'+E.EmpName+'.'
    from @Employees E
    inner join Hierarchy H on H.EmpID=E.ReportsTo
)

--Result
Select Space((Level-(Select Top(1) Level from Hierarchy H2 Where H2.EmpName=@manager))*4) + EmpName
  from Hierarchy H
  where CHARINDEX('.'+(Select Top(1) E.EmpName from @Employees E Where E.EmpName=@manager)+'.', H.FullyQualifiedName) > 0
  order by H.FullyQualifiedName
```

How do I get the counts of the projects for each employee?.

Comment: is the hierarchic multi tiered?  X levels of undetermined nature? and what rdbms?

Answer (score 0):

Managers aggregate count of projects all employees.

```
--Result
Select Space((Level-(Select Top(1) Level from Hierarchy H2 Where H2.EmpName=@manager))*4) + EmpName,
       COALESCE(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END,
       CASE WHEN Level = 0 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER() END, 0) AS cnt
from Hierarchy H LEFT JOIN @PROJECTS p ON H.EMPID = p.EMPID
where CHARINDEX('.'+(Select Top(1) E.EmpName from @Employees E Where E.EmpName=@manager)+'.', H.FullyQualifiedName) > 0
order by H.FullyQualifiedName
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11401)

OR try this

```
--Result
Select Space((Level-(Select Top(1) Level from Hierarchy H2 Where H2.EmpName=@manager))*4) + EmpName,       
       CASE WHEN Level = 0 THEN SUM(CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END) OVER() END AS totalCnt,
       CASE WHEN ID IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END AS cntSingle,              
       o.cntChild
from Hierarchy H OUTER APPLY (
                              SELECT COUNT(p.PROJNAME) AS cntChild
                              FROM @Employees e LEFT JOIN @PROJECTS p ON e.EmpID = p.EMPID
                              WHERE h.EmpID = e.ReportsTo
                              ) o
                 LEFT JOIN @PROJECTS p ON H.EMPID = p.EMPID                           
where CHARINDEX('.'+(Select Top(1) E.EmpName from @Employees E Where E.EmpName=@manager)+'.', H.FullyQualifiedName) > 0
order by H.FullyQualifiedName
```

Comment: Great but the 2nd level (ex: bob has to have the count of that are aggregate of the children)

Comment: but his childrens don't have projects

Comment: If you add one or 2 children it still shows 1 .  Do we need to partition it by Level ?

Comment: DECLARE @Projects Table (ID INT,EMPID INT, PROJNAME VARCHAR(50))
INSERT INTO @PROJECTS(ID,EMPID,PROJNAME)  
    SELECT 1,19,'ABCD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,5,'EFGH'   UNION ALL

    SELECT 3,16,'ADAD'  UNION ALL

    SELECT 4,6,'FSDFSD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,8,'DSDSDSD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,8,'DSDSADDSD' UNION ALL
 SELECT 7,20,'55555' UNION ALL
 SELECT 55,12,'sdsds' UNION ALL
 SELECT 22,13,'dfgdfg'

Comment: (No column name) cnt
Jacob 6
    Bob 1
        Michael 1
        Paul 1
    Jess NULL
    Steve 1
        John 1

Comment: Could you illustrate your desire result, please?